# How to build a formatted string in Java?

Tags: java, string, string-interpolation

I am somewhat new to Java but I dislike the heavy use of string concatenation I'm seeing in my textbook.

For example, I'd like to **avoid** doing this:

```
String s = "x:"+x+"," y:"+y+", z:"+z;
```

Is it possible to build a string using a notation similar to this:

```
String s = new String("x:%d, y:%d, z:%d", x, y, z);
```

### Input

```
x = 1
y = 2
z = 3
```

### Output

```
"x:1, y:2, z:3"
```

Note: I understand I can output formatted strings using `System.out.printf()` but I want to store the formatted string in a variable.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
String s = String.format("x:%d, y:%d, z:%d", x, y, z);
```

[Java Howto - Format a string](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0463.html)

Comment: @macek np. I almost always have to look it up myself, I keep mixing up java and c# syntax.

Comment: this functionality is based on java.util.Formatter, which you can use directly for extended formatting.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is possible. The `String` class contains the `format()` method, which works like you expect.
Example:

```
String s = String.format("x:%d, y:%d, z:%d", x, y, z);
```

Here you have more details about formatting:
[formatter syntax](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)

Answer (score 2):

Since JDK 15:

```
var s = "x:%d, y:%d, z:%d".formatted(x, y, z);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do interpolation using Java's String Templates feature.
It is described in [JEP 430](https://openjdk.org/jeps/430), and it appears in JDK 21 as a preview feature.  Here is an example use:

```java
String info = STR."x:\{x}, y:\{y}, z:\{z}";
```